# Alternate row colours angular material table

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I am wondering how I target the even/odd rows inside a `Angular Material Table` so that I can set the even/odd rows a different background colour.

I setup my `ClaimFileHistoryDataSource` class:

```
claimClientInformation: ClaimFileHistory[];
dataSource : ClaimFileHistoryDataSource;
displayedColumns = ['TypeImg', 'Description', 'Agent'];


export class ClaimFileHistoryDataSource extends DataSource<ClaimFileHistory> {

    constructor(private _claimFileHistory: ClaimFileHistory[]) {
      super();
    }

    connect(): Observable<ClaimFileHistory[]> {
      return Observable.of(this._claimFileHistory);
    }

    disconnect() {}
}
```

On `NgInit` I make a call to my service to go and get the data I need and populate the `DataSource`:

```
this._claimFileHistoryService.getClaimFileHistoryById().subscribe(response => {
  this.claimClientInformation = response;       
  this.dataSource = new ClaimFileHistoryDataSource(this.claimClientInformation);
});
```

This is fine and the Data is coming back as it should.

In the HTML the `Mat-Table` looks like this:

```
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="TypeImg">
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"><img [src]='row.TypeImg' height="40px"></mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <div>
            <span class="d-block">{{row.Description}}</span>
            <span class="d-block">{{row.Date}}</span>
          </div>

        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Agent">
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Agent}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

Again I was wondering how do I go about getting the Odd/Even rows of the table and setting them a different row background colour?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Use Following CSS in your .css or .scss file to set the different style for even/odd row:

```css
.mat-row:nth-child(even){
    background-color: red;
}
        
.mat-row:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: for some reason this didn't work for me, instead this answer helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56349859/9625054

Comment: Check if "mat-row" is a class, in my case it didn't, so I just use it as a element

Comment: I had to use the class ".mat-mdc-row" instead of ".mat-row" to get it to work.

Answer (score 61):

Updating this answer with a newer approach to future developers who may come to this question.

Material Angular now offers some variables to row indexes.

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="
              let row;
              let even = even; 
              columns: displayedColumns;" 
         [ngClass]="{gray: even}"></mat-row>
```

In you CSS file: `.gray { background-color: #f5f5f5 }`

There are other properties like: `index`, `count`, `first`, `last`, `even` and `odd`.

You can find out more on [Angular Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples), more specifically on section "Table showing each row context properties"

Comment: This is the better option if you're using expandable detail rows otherwise the coloring will get off

Comment: Newbie question: Why do you need `let even = even` but not 'let row = row`?

Comment: @xr280xr check https://gist.github.com/JanMalch/800cc0e1e448961fa5d93289e24e26fb#implementing-logic and look for $implicit, that is the `row` in our case

Answer (score 10):

You can apply colors to rows based on condition as well.

For an instance if the cell value is equal to 100,then change the color of the row to red.

```
     <tr class="matheader-row" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns; 
      let i = index; let even = even;" [class.rowStyle]="row['myColumn']=='100'"
                [ngClass]="{rowcolor: even}">
        </tr>
```

**css**

```
.rowStyle{
background-color:red;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Above scenario will work if your columns have myColumn as one of the columns.
Also using even property you can apply the required color styling `[ngClass]="{rowcolor: even}`

Answer (score 5):

if you use themes a *transparent* css looks nice:

```css
.mat-row:nth-child(odd){
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.025);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunatly none of the above answers worked for me (i'm using multiTemplateDataRows), but after tweaking Gustavo Lopez answer i got it to work as below:

```
<tr *matRowDef="
          let row;
          let index = dataIndex;
          columns: displayedColumns;" 
     [ngClass]="{alternate: index % 2 == 0 }"></tr>´
```

And the css is as previous answer:

```
.alternate { background-color: #f5f5f5 }
```

It seems like no of the properties like odd,even or index work when you have multiTemplateDataRows but fortunately they've solved the index property with dataIndex (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12793#issuecomment-415356860). Hopefully this will help others that have expandable rows.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works perfectly when using expandable rows

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**With Angular Material 16**

```
.mat-mdc-row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1; /* Set the background color for even rows */
}

.mat-mdc-row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff; /* Set the background color for odd rows */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers of @mohit uprim and @Gustavo Lopes did work for me for a Material Angular datatable. But whenever I hover above the line, the row gets its initial default colour (white) and restores the new CSS colour on mouse-out event. So, adding "important" flag should fix it :

```
.some-class-name {
    background-color: blue !important; 
}
```