# Alternate color with Angular Material mat-table with parent child rows

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have an Angular Material `mat-table` which I used CSS styling for alternate row colors. Here is the CSS styling:

```css
.mat-row:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #e4f0ec;
}

.mat-row:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

This works when my mat-table does not have defined child rows. When I added another `ng-container` which is specified with "expandedDetail", this does not work anymore. All the rows is white but the expanded child rows are colored.

I followed the example from material.angular.io

I see other example for row styling but they use tr tags. In the example and my code, I used an `ng-container`, th and td tags for each column.

Any help is appreciated.

I added the project to stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bcxtv

Here is the HTML code I used

```html
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
       class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <div class="example-element-diagram">
          <div class="example-element-position"> {{element.position}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-symbol"> {{element.symbol}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-name"> {{element.name}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-weight"> {{element.weight}} </div>
        </div>
        <div class="example-element-description">
          {{element.description}}
          <span class="example-element-description-attribution"> -- Wikipedia </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does the stackblitz link run for you? There are a number of errors

Comment: Sorry, I posted the code but I am new at stackblitz. The code works on my visual studio code... but I can't get it to work online

Answer (score 11, accepted):

dang it - this took me too long to find out and the worse.. I don't know excatly why it's working..

```
.mat-row:nth-child(2n+1){
  background-color: #e4f0ec;
}
.mat-row:not(:nth-child(4n+1)){
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

I hope I could help you :)

Answer (score 5):

Thought I would follow up on this issue as I recently faced it and found pieces of useful information that lead to the following elegant approach:
In your table html we can utilize the built in "odd" or "even" properties, depending on which color you want first.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let odd = odd; columns: columnNames;" [class.striped-row]="odd"></tr>
```

Then in your CSS add the following:

```
.striped-row {
    background-color: #ececec;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `mat-table` with `multiTemplateDataRows`, the rows are indexed by `dataIndex`.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i = dataIndex; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row" [ngClass]="{'alt-row': i % 2}"></tr>
```

See https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12793

Answer (score 2):

You could set your own class on the row and then target it, so as to not mess around with n-depth and complex selectors that break as your html changes.

```
.my-row {
    background-color: #e4f0ec;
}

.my-row__alternate {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}


<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay; let i = index"
  class="my-row"
  [class.my-row__alternate]="i % 2">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below css for table row and multiTemplateDataRows. This will strip group of table row + multiTemplateDataRows.

```
.mat-row:nth-child(4n-1), .mat-row:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: #e4f0ec;
}
```

Comment: This more like the expected result. The accepted answer delivers the child rows always in the same color. The answer above paints the child in the same color as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might need this.

```
   .mat-row:nth-child(2n+1) {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .mat-row:nth-child(2n) {
        background-color: #F2F5F7;
    }

    .mat-row:nth-child(4n) {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .mat-row:nth-child(4n+1) {
        background-color: #F2F5F7;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with mat-option css, it had to have alternating background. Solved it with this:

```
.mat-option {
    &:nth-child(2n+1) {
        background-color: #f0efff;
    }
    &:not(:nth-child(2n+1)) {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Note that second nth-child has ":not" in front

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mat-mdc-row:nth-child(2n+1){
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.03);
}
.mat-mdc-row:nth-child(2n){
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

I don't know if it's because of the version of mat-table or not but I had to use the mat_**mdc**_row class to get it working.